# NavigationStack hides the second view's navigation title and toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

So I built an app where you can add your personal expenses and it works fine but I added a loginView with faceID and when you login with that, it hides the second view's add and edit button, besides the search bar where you can filter the expenses

Here's the code that worked before i added the loginView

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var PEviewModel = PEViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
       // NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                PersonalExpensesView()
                    .environmentObject(PEviewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Personal expenses list", systemImage: "dollarsign.circle")
                    }
                // another view
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Graph", systemImage: "chart.bar.fill")
                    }
            }
        }
        //.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
}
```

The MainView contains the two views you can navigate in. I added that `navigationStack` and the `navigationBarBackButton()` just to delete the back bar button so I could try if it worked (it didn't). PersonalExpensesView has the following (and it worked before the logInUpdate)

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                // all the listing of personal expenses and stuff
                .navigationTitle("Personal Expenses")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        EditButton()
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            showingSheet = true
                        } label: {
                            Label("Add Book", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $textFilter)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                NewPEView()
                    .environmentObject(PEviewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code I added later (the logIn code) :

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button() {
                    authenticate()
                } label: {
                    Label("Usar Face ID", systemImage: "faceid")
                }
                .customButton()
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $unlocked){// authenticate() sets unlocked true
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
```

So the correct UI (without using login) is the following
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s73wq.png)

And with login: [bugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUJ2D.png)

I tried using a NavigationStack as I showed in the `MainView()`

Comment: You can not add a tabview inside a navigation stack. This will lead to incorrect behaviour. Especially if you have navigation stack inside the tab. You could dd a sheet on the main view that show the login view.

Comment: @PtitXav Thank you very much, I fixed it using a sheet as you said. The thing is that I wanted to present a full screen view for the login, so there is no way to do that if the next view has a TabView?

Comment: One way to add a full view is to use a @State var isLogged = false. Then in the code do so if isLogged display data view else display login view. When user is logged update the state var and SwiftUI will display the data view.